# Search text box using web services & without using web services in .net using ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using HTML controls while using Ajax in my .net project. Now I want to make my text box to be autocomplete. I am fetching a data using a query for the respective typed text but i am not sure how to bind that data to text box and show it the way it is being displayed in google and other famous sites. I would also love to know the way using web services. Which way is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the [jquery autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)? 
[Here](http://www.codevoyeur.com/Articles/10/ASP.NET-MVC-HtmlHelper-Extensions-for-jQuery-AutoComplete.aspx) you hava a nice example of how to integrate it with asp.net mvc.
Instead of using a web service to obtain the data, you can use a controller action instead.
Regards

Comment: I absolutely agree on using a controller action for this! There's no need for the complexity of a web service.